# Chicken fat mixing with oil and attaching to fish when frying chicken and fish in the same oil

Tags: chicken, fish, deep-frying, batter, breading

This question follows from [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/122681/will-cross-contamination-not-happen-when-deep-frying-breaded-chicken-and-battere) question. The answer there does not satisfactorily answer this question. Fish and chicken are not the same. It is possible that fat from chicken does not mix with oil, right?

When battered fish and breaded chicken are being fried in the same fryer, will fat from the chicken get mixed with the oil and attach to the fish? Will the remains of chicken still stick to the fish in the fryer, even though both the fish and chicken are battered and breaded, respectively?

Comment: Isn't this really the same question you linked to, except worded a bit differently?

Comment: @moscafj It is largely the same but here I focus on the specific case of chicken contaminating the fish

Comment: @moscafj It does not answer it entirely. Fish and chicken are not the same. It is possible that fat from chicken does not mix with oil, right?

Comment: define "contaminate". Is someone allergic to fish, chicken, ingredients in the batter, ingredients in the breading? Is someone a vegetarian who will eat fish but doesn't want chicken fat in their fish?

Comment: @KateGregory _Is someone a vegetarian who will eat fish but doesn't want chicken fat in their fish?_ This.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter if the chicken fat might reach the fish ... it is enough if it reaches the batter, which the vegetarian will be eating. While the chicken fat may not dissolve into the frying oil, if any fat leaves the chicken, it could reach the fish batter. Imagine putting an apple in cold water and then pouring in a little oil. The oil and water won't mix, but the apple is likely to get oily nonetheless.

Comment: @KateGregory Ok so cross-contamination is happening? Another point of view is that the high temperature of the oil will denature/kill any remains of the meats.

Comment: your vegetarians may vary. Mine would consider fragments of denatured animal protein to still count as animal material.  My family members who don't eat pork prefer we not cook their chicken in a pan that has had pork cooked in it, no matter how clean that pan has become since then. People make their choices and have their preferences.

Comment: @KateGregory _People make their choices and have their preferences._  I understand people have their preferences but I am concerned about a very specific case: Does fat/any chicken remains get denatured after being released in the deep frying oil?

Comment: I don't know because I don't care. A denatured chicken protein is still an animal product, so I haven't looked into this at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141541/discussion-between-a-sid-and-kate-gregory).